# creating sql without using min

Tags: sql, subquery, min

In jennifer widom's dbclass, she gives an example of getting a  colleges paired up with the highest gpa of their applicants.. The sql is below

```
select college.cname, state, gpa       
  from college, apply, student
 where college.cname = apply.cname
   and apply.sid = student.sid
   and gpa >= all (select gpa 
                     from student,apply
                    where student.sid = apply.sid
   and apply.cname = college.cname);
```

I am wondering how to create the query to find colleges paired with the **minimum** gpa of applicants

I know this can be done as below

```
select college.cname, state, gpa       
  from college, apply, student
 where college.cname = apply.cname
   and apply.sid = student.sid
   and gpa = (select min(gpa) from student);
```

But how do I do this ,**without using min** ?

Comment: by standard sql.. so all databases should behave alike

Comment: Except they don't -- ANSI exists for this very reason.

Comment: Why don't you just answer this simple question? What is your DBMS? And at the same time you expect answers to your big question?

Comment: why the negative vote? Prof widom's lessons ask you to use standard sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select college.cname,state,gpa       
from college c
    join apply a On a.cname = c.cname 
    join student s On s.sid = apply.sid
where Not exists(select * from student 
                 Where gpa < s.gpa);
```

Comment: thanks,I modified this a bit ( using table variables fro apply.sid and college.cname ) and it gives the desired result